# Prevent <button> being clicked without disabling it

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my page i have a `<button>` with an `<input type="number" />` inside, when a user clicks in the `<input>` or it's spinner buttons the `<button>`'s click event will fire and the `<button>` obtains the `:active` style.
Setting `<button disabled="disabled">` does prevent click event from firing but the `<button>` obtains the disabled style.

What i am looking for is how to make the `<button>` unclickable using simple Javascript, CSS, or HTML without hijacking click events, disabling it, or putting something transparent on top.
It should appear normal but when clicked it must not change style or fire a click event.

What i have http://jsfiddle.net/tzu8gLvm/

Comment: btw, HTML doesn't need or want trailing "/" on [void elements](https://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#void-elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself after some experimenting.
the reason why i didn't want to disable my `<button>` was that it will look disabled.
Apparently the `:disabled` style can be overridden with `button:disabled { color: black; }`, this makes it perfectly acceptable for me to disable it.

```js
function disable(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).disabled = 'disabled';
}

function enable(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  opacity: 1;
}
#orderbutton3:disabled {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
Begin (clicking the number input clicks the button) :
<br/>
<button id="orderbutton1" type="button">
  Order&nbsp;
  <input type="number" style="width: 38px;" name="amount" min="0" value="0" max="999">
  <b>&times;</b >
  &nbsp;
</button >
<br/>
<hr/>
This is what i get when i just disable it :
<br/>
<button id="orderbutton2" type="button">
  Order&nbsp;
  <input type="number" onmouseover="disable('orderbutton2');" onmouseout="enable('orderbutton2');" style="width: 38px;" name="amount" min="0" value="0" max="999">
  <b>&times;</b >
  &nbsp;
</button >
<br/>
<hr/>
What i ended up with (clicking the input does not click the button and the button appears clickable because i have overridden the text color) :
<br/>
<button id="orderbutton3" type="button">
  Order&nbsp;
  <input type="number" onmouseover="disable('orderbutton3');" onmouseout="enable('orderbutton3');" style="width: 38px;" name="amount" min="0" value="0" max="999">
  <b>&times;</b >
  &nbsp;
</button >
```

Comment: I'm glad you finally did the right thing and used `disabled`. However, that's not an acceptable answer to your question until you rephrase it to explain your actual constraint, which was purely graphical all along.

Answer (score 2):

Your restrictions cover a lot of good solutions. What's wrong with `disabled`??

But as it happens, there is a CSS way. You can set `pointer-events: none` on the input, and clicks will just pass through.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.
I would like to refrain from disabled because i don't want users thinking that they can't click the button.
Only problem now is that if i click on the `input` the button with `pointer-events: none` will do nothing (as wanted) but when i click again in the input it will click the button.
Looks like this has something to do with the focus...

Comment: pointer-events: none
prevent mouse and touch clicking
but if you focus on the button and click Enter or Spacebar it will be clicked

Comment: True. Then again, the situation is messed up. Also, is the input inside a `<form>` and is the button's type a non-default (submit) value ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the preventDefault() function in javascript to prevent an action to be fired. Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i also didn't want the button to obtain the `:active` style, i already tried stripping the click event but the `<button>` still looks very `:active` when clicked.